# Embedded SWIG python debug version will not let me import

Tags: debugging, python-2.7, swig

I have generated a SWIG python binding of a C++ library. I would like for others to be able to script it using python directly, but I would also like to embed python in my application so users can setup python scripts to modify variables at runtime. When I run python or python_d I can import my release and debug versions of my library with no issues and then use them. However, when I try and embed them I can run the following code with no issues in release mode, but in debug mode I get the error below.

Embedded code:

```
Py_SetProgramName("AnimatLab");
Py_Initialize();

PyRun_SimpleString("import os\n"
    "os.chdir(\"C:/Projects/AnimatLabSDK/AnimatLabPublicSource/bin\")\n"
"import AnimatSimPy\n");
Py_Finalize();
```

Error:

```
C:\Projects\AnimatLabSDK\AnimatLabPublicSource\bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named AnimatSimPy
```

I know the _AnimatSimPy_d.pyd works in debug mode because I can import and use it when I run python_d, but for some reason it will not run when embedded. Does anyone have any ideas on why this is failing? I am linking the debug version to python27_d.dll on a 64 bit windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I am not sure why, but in debug mode it required me to append to my paths to add the directory where the dll was and not just set the working directory. For release mode it worked without this. So if I run the code below it works in both debug and release mode from the embedded code.

```
Py_SetProgramName("AnimatLab");
Py_Initialize();

PyRun_SimpleString("import os\n"
                   "import sys\n"
                   "sys.path.append(\"C:/Projects/AnimatLabSDK/AnimatLabPublicSource/bin\")\n"
                   "os.chdir(\"C:/Projects/AnimatLabSDK/AnimatLabPublicSource/bin\")\n"
        "import AnimatSimPy\n");
Py_Finalize();
```